# Can I Set an ostream Delimiter

Tags: c++, delimiter, ostream

I want to space delimit a lot of inputs to a stream.
I know that I can use `std::ostream_iterator`'s delimiter constructor, but not all of my inputs are of the same type.

Is there a way that I can tell a stream to use a delimiter by default?

```
std::ostringstream foo;
foo << 1 << 1.2 << "bar" // I want this to print "1 1.2 bar "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the stream something like the following, (*just a basic idea*)

```
struct mystream 
{
     mystream (std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}
     std::ostream&   os;
};

template <class T> 
mystream& operator<< (mystream& con, const T& x) 
{ 
     con.os << x << " "; // add extra delimeter
     return con; 
}


int main() 
{
    std::ostringstream foo;
    mystream c(foo) ; // mystream c( std::cout ) ;

    c << 1 << 1.2 << "bar" ;
}
```

See [*here*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b37a17e0c0c0ad45)

Comment: `c << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(3) << std::hexfloat << 3.14159;`

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle this functionality into a stream using stream buffers and virtual functions. For example:

```c++
class space_delimited_output_buffer : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    space_delimited_output_buffer(std::streambuf* sbuf)
        : m_sbuf(sbuf)
    { }

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c)
    {
        return m_sbuf->sputc(c);
    }

    virtual int sync()
    {
        if (ok_to_write)
            this->sputc(' ');
        else
            ok_to_write = true;

        return internal_sync();
    }
private:
    std::streambuf* m_sbuf;
    bool ok_to_write = false;

    int internal_sync()
    {
        return m_sbuf->pubsync();
    }
};

class space_delimited_output_stream
    : public std::ostream
    , private virtual space_delimited_output_buffer
{
public:
    space_delimited_output_stream(std::ostream& os)
        : std::ostream(this)
        , space_delimited_output_buffer(os.rdbuf())
    {
        this->tie(this); 
    }
};

int main() {
    space_delimited_output_stream os(std::cout);
    os << "abc" << 123 << "xyz";
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/D3LVfF)